# Identify possible Kona

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

I recently found this bike at a thrift store and although it looks pretty haggard I'm thinking it is a Kona. Some help identifying the model and such would be appreciated.

Serial number is F712K1083 and nearby are the numbers 81-30 as well. I have no way of knowing what parts are original but on the side of the seat there is a K
I looked around online already and it seems similar to the Kona Kahuna but I'm no expert.

I gathered from some things I read that the serial number can be read as: F=Fairly Factory/7=1997/12=December but that's as far as I got. If that is correct, does the K stand for the model?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does it say on the side of the top tube?  Can you give us a better picture of that?

Comment: It says Kona, but the last owner did a cheap spackled paint job so I'm unsure if that part is authentic. I'm not around the bike at the moment but I will be later if more pictures are needed

Comment: Well, the pictures above are very poor -- poor lighting, awkward angle, etc -- so it would be difficult to identify a manufacturer from them.  In fact, it's difficult to identify the manufacturer of any fairly recent frame from any photo, as the styles are very similar.  Yours appears to be a classic low-end mountain bike, available from any of a dozen manufacturers.

Comment: I didn't focus so much on quality photos because i was hoping someone would be familiar with the style of serial number at least enough to confirm whether its a kona or not

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort to decode the serial number as far as you have.  That's a lot more than shown in most 'identify my bike' type questions.

Comment: doesn't look that kona-ish as the seat tube isn't sloping, and I dont recognise the seat stay design. If you can add a photo from the rear pointing towards the saddle, it might help ID it.

Comment: That K is not the Kona logo.  I don't think that they ever made straight pillar seatposts.

Comment: Not an answer - did you know your top tube has a dent in it?   That saddle is not original - it just looks wrong in style, colour, and squishyness for the bike.   And in picture1 it looks like the work KONA is written on in permanent marker pen.

Comment: I don't believe Kona has ever put a saddle like that on a bicycle (coil sprung).  Someone can feel free to correct me, but I don't think it's a Kona saddle.

Answer (score 1):

The K logo is definitely not Kona, my daily rider is a Kona Fire Mountain. KonIA (Konia) maybe? Lower end MTB manufacturer.

BTW my saddle and seat pole definitely NOT Kona. I broke and replaced them myself!

[image: logo]

[image]

Comment: Most of this is a separate question about interpreting serial numbers.  Try asking it as a separate question.  Please take a brief moment to view the [tour] to learn how SE is a Q&A site, not a common chatty forum style.

Comment: I edited out the question part. You can find it in the edit history by clicking on the "edited [at this time]" link, so you can copy-paste it into a new question.